# Why do we need latch in DAC?

Tags: adc, dac

[image]

I don't see any difference without no latch and just putting a CS bar signal on DAC itself. Why do we need latch for digital data but no latch for analog data converter? Is there any logic?

Comment: What do you imagine that a "CS bar" signal on the DAC itself would actually do?

Comment: Consider two scenarios: 1) the DataBus continuosly contains the data that you want to convert, you cannot use the DataBus for anything else. 2) the DataBus is also used for other devices so the data that you want to convert is only available at a certain moment in time.

Comment: What is the purpose of a latch?  For your CS solution to work, the 8085 would have to wait (additional clocks cycles) until the conversion was complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That DAC is an antique, as are the other components in that circuit. You need to think back to before 1980 to "get" that circuit.

Imagine the DAC is a series of 8 FET switches and 15 precision resistors and nothing else ... and the -15V rail is a clue that these aren't modern FETs either.

To add a register would involve adding at least 48 extra FETs, (6 per bit) making it a vastly more complicated chip, and in an analog process with very poor performance (low speed and high power consumption) compared to TTL digital logic. The first CMOS logic series (CD4000) could barely clock at 1 MHz versus about 20MHz for the 74LS373.

It would be a hopeless design : instead, let the digital designers build a fast efficient register, and keep this chip in a pure analog process with no performance compromises.

(Latches for analog signals are called "sample and hold" circuits, and indeed most ADCs of that era did use them)

Even the 8085 CPU was NMOS, consuming far more power than the same design in CMOS. Which means they hadn't figured out how to put both NMOS and PMOS transistors on the same chip (and retain any kind of speed : though RCA made the above CD4000, which had a niche market)

Nowadays of course process technology is far more advanced and you can combine decent analog and decent digital circuitry on the same chip.

Answer (score 1):

The DAC has no chip select. Imagine it is just a R2R DAC. DAC will constantly convert whatever is on the data bus to analog value, and the system will contain other peripherals such as RAM and ROM which are constantly being accessed and thus there will be constantly changes on the data bus.

Comment: But in ADC we didn't use this..Oh so makes sense only digital data as computer also uses digital data. Thanks.

Comment: The ADC has a sample and hold filter, which is equivalent to the latch.

Answer (score 1):

> just putting a CS bar signal on DAC itself.

It's that engineering 4-letter word again, 'just'.

Putting a CS bar onto the DAC only makes sense if you put a latch in the DAC. That particular 1408 has no internal latch, it is a bare 8 bit converter, and will faithfully, instantly change its output to whatever the present digital input is.

Most DACs today have internal latches. Back in the dinosaur era, when integrated silicon was expensive, they didn't.

Comment: but why no latch for ADC? Because computer is digital data?

Comment: @gidser Some ADCs have internal latches, some don't. All ADCs produce a digital version of an input at some instant in time. Some MCUs involve external buffers or latches, some don't. Post a circuit with an ADC and then we can discuss your particular one.

Comment: The DAC was designed for an external latch.  Asking why makes no sense.  The days of MSI and LSI.

Comment: @gidser I've already told you why no internal latch - Back in the dinosaur era, when integrated silicon was expensive, you were lucky to get the analogue part of the DAC, the switches, the resistors, integrated. There was no silicon budget left over for a latch that you could provide externally.